# MySQL Error when dropping index (errno 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1025

I've got problem with dropping foreign key index, I always get the same error

```
 ALTER TABLE `comments` DROP INDEX `id_user`
```

which outputs

```
 1025 - Error on rename of './postuj_cz1/#sql-d834_a0c704' 
 to './postuj_cz1/comments' (errno: 150)
```

The `id_user` on the other table is simple primary key index.

I'm using MySQL version 5.0.85

Comment: Try dropping all foreign keys to the table first.

Comment: Actually I don't have any fk to the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](http://forums.devarticles.com/mysql-development-50/mysql-foreign-key-problem-errno-150t-7704.html), the error relates to the definition of the primary key field.  The error isn't about the foreign key index.

Check the primary key for the `COMMENTS` table to make sure it does not have the `UNSIGNED` keyword while the `COMMENTS.id_user` foreign key had the UNSIGNED keyword. This keyword was causing the problem - inconsistent type of field.

To fix, add the `UNSIGNED` keyword to the primary key definition for the `COMMENTS` table.  Or remove the `UNSIGNED` keyword from the foreign key definition...

Answer (score 13):

There are other causes too. For example I had a unique index involving two separate foreign key columns. I had to drop the foreign keys in question before I could drop the unique index. (And obviously you can add the foreign keys back afterward.)

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem in my case.

Comment: exactly,  dropping the unique index caused my foreign key to refer a "non unique" field which is not possible

Answer (score 6):

INNODB : this could be as simple as removing the Relation before dropping the Index.

Comment: The relation was, for my case, locking everything. So, removing relations, next removing the index, next creating new index, then, restore relations

Answer (score 2):

The index is for an foreign key on 'user' table, so 
In first, try this command:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table
```

Find the name of the constraint corresponding to the index on the foreign key,

and after that, try the command:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table DROP FOREIGN KEY FK_myconstraintcode
```

WARNING: If you try to drop the foreign key with the foreign key name, you will have an error to!

Comment: this was a good solution for me, seem to be that foreing key can't be removed with the drop index sentence.