# Running remove_column not working in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, migrate

I have a very simple migration:

```
class RemoveAuthorIdFromBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :books, :author_id
  end

end
```

But I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Error on rename of './mysite_staging/#sql-3b1_3c78' to './mysite_staging/books' (errno: 150): ALTER TABLE `books` DROP `author_id`
```

This is the description of the table:

```
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| author_id        | int(11)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| title            | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| teaser           | varchar(500)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| description      | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cover_image      | varchar(255)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| publication_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| enabled          | tinyint(1)    | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| created_at       | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at       | datetime      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| excerpt          | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| featured         | tinyint(1)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| site_id          | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Any clues?

Comment: What does your current table looks like? ('rails db' and then describe books;). Also, what versions are you using(Rails, Mysql2. OS?)

Comment: Rails 3, mysql2, Ubuntu on Amazon ec2.

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/1451042/684934

Comment: This might have to do with the fact that the author_id is an index. Depending on what SQL you're using and how it's configured it might be a problem.  try removing the index before removing the column. (remove_index :books, :author_id)

Comment: Index name 'index_books_on_author_id' on table 'books' does not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason a foreign key constraint was breaking the drop sentence.

I did the following:

```
show create table books;
```

Looked at the foreign key name and then:

```
alter table books drop foreign key books_ibfk_1;
```

Then rake db:migrate worked.

Answer (score 6):

If anyone still facing this with Rails 4 and above, then you could do the following

> remove_reference(:books, :author, index: true, foreign_key: true)